# File permission as a four digit number in c

Tags: c, permissions

I am trying to get the permission of a file as a four digit number.
I have created a file lol with permission 0777

```
struct stat st;
stat("lol", &st);
printf("%d",st.st_mode);
```

When I test this, the result is not 0777. Why?

Comment: Let me guess, you get [`511`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=777+octal+in+decimal)?

Comment: 33279 not 511, why? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: First read about the [octal number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), and the [`"%o"` `printf` format](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Then you have to know that file permission flags are not limited to the ones usually used (rwx for user, group and others) there may be other flags as well. Use the flags defined in [`<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) to find out what flags are set.